# Multisession configuration in google app engine

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, session, spring-security, session-cookies

I am developing an application with GAE and Spring (MVC and security).

My application has 2 'environements', the frontoffice and the backoffice. 
Each of this environments has a different session needs. For example in the 
frontoffice I want a 10 minutes session and I want to store some objects.
In the backoffice I want some other objects and more than 10 minutes of session.

In a normal J2EE environment I would create 2 EARs with different web.xml configs.
How do I acheive this with GAE? if it is not possible, is there a good workaround with Spring?

Any idea?
Jordi.

Comment: Your question is not very clear and does not clearly state what problem you are facing and what is that you are trying to resolve. If you want to get help, some more detail and problem statement would be helpful

Comment: I have rewritten the question, I hope is clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deploy 2 WARs with different **<version>** (`appengine-web.xml`). As long as they're in the same `MYAPP.appspot.com`, they will share same datastore.

Each will have different URL, e.g. `frontoffice.MYAPP.appspot.com` and `backoffice.MYAPP.appspot.com`. You can set one URL to be default so it can be accessed from `MYAPP.appspot.com`.